# Best Spatial interpolation method for regularly spaced data

Tags: r, geospatial, arcgis, weather, kriging

I have a set of regularly spaced weather data that  need to interpolate into a spatial surface. I was wondering the best spatial prediction method that can be used for this interpolation process, and software. Thanks

Comment: Primarly opinion-based and too broad. Voted to close.

Comment: Dissertations have been written on the topic of what interpolation method is best. While you can try asking on GIS.SE instead of StackOverflow, you will still need to narrow down the question to specific application (R or ArcGIS) and no more than two possible interpolation methods.